# How can create secure web socket server (Wss) in C#?

Tags: c#, websocket, tls1.2, httplistener

How can i create secure web socket server (WSS). ??

Currently the web socket server implemented over HTTPListener.

The data communication between server and client should be secure. How can i implement the secure communication ?

Sample code as follows:

```
class WebsocketServer
{
    public async void Start(string httpListenerPrefix)
    {
        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(httpListenerPrefix);
        httpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext httpListenerContext = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
            if (httpListenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                ProcessRequest(httpListenerContext); 
            } 
            else
            {
                httpListenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                httpListenerContext.Response.Close(); 
            }
        }
    }

    private async void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext httpListenerContext)
    {
        WebSocketContext webSocketContext = null;
        webSocketContext = await httpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
        WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;       
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
        while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
            if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            else 
            {
                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveResult.Count), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, receiveResult.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I voted as "too broad". Here's a dupe too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135220/how-to-enable-ssl-in-websocket-with-system-net-httplistener

Comment: Server and client data communication is encrypted?

Comment: Use the `wss` URI scheme. Done, SSL takes care of the rest.

Comment: Do in need code extra to implement wss URI scheme?

Comment: Server side : string httpListenerPrefix ="https:\\localhost:80\"                        
, client side : "wss:\\localhost" .  is this works well just modifing uri scheme ? or do i need to code extra to support secure URi scheme?

Comment: how can i create secure data transfer over web socket?